# What is the probability that it is raining?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

A bus comes around your house every day.
When it rains, there is a 20% probability that it is going to be late.
When it doesn't rain, there is a 10% probability that it's going to be late.
The probability that it will rain is 40%.
Today, the bus was late. What is the probability that it was raining?
(By the way, the correct answer is 0.571, but I couldn't figure out how to get there.)

Comment: Are you familiar with Bayes' rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Bayes' Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem),

$$ P[A|B] = \frac{P[B|A]\cdot P[A]}{P[B]} $$

This gives us

$$ P[\text{Rain}|\text{Late}] = \frac{P[\text{Late}|\text{Rain}]\cdot P[\text{Rain}]}{P[\text{Late}]} $$

Of these, we know

$$ P[\text{Late}|\text{Rain}] = 0.2 , $$
$$ P[\text{Rain}] = 0.4 . $$

So, we still need $P[\text{Late}]$.

For this, we can use the fact that

$$ P[A] = P[A \cap B]+P[A \cap B^C] . $$

This gives us

$$ P[\text{Late}]=P[\text{Late} \cap \text{Rain}]+P[\text{Late} \cap \text{No Rain}] $$

$$ =P[\text{Late} | \text{Rain}]\cdot P[\text{Rain}]+P[\text{Late} | \text{No Rain}]\cdot P[\text{No Rain}] $$

$$ = 0.2 \cdot 0.4 + 0.1 \cdot (1-0.4) $$
$$ = 0.14 $$

Substituting these values all into the expression we found above, we have:

$$ P[\text{Rain}|\text{Late}] = \frac{P[\text{Late}|\text{Rain}]\cdot P[\text{Rain}]}{P[\text{Late}]} $$

$$ = \frac{0.2 \cdot 0.4}{0.14} $$
$$ \approx 0.571 $$

Answer (score 0):

We use the rules of conditional probability.
Generally speaking:
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{A}|\text{B}) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(\text{A} \text{ and } \text{B})}{\mathbb{P}(\text{B})}$$
Where $\mathbb{P}(\text{A}|\text{B})$ means "probability of A given B".

So here we have the probability that it is raining is
$$\frac{\text{probability that it is raining and the bus was late}}{\text{probability that the bus was late}}$$
The probability that the bus was late is $0.4 \times 0.2 + 0.6 \times 0.1$. (The sum of the case the bus is late and it rains and the bus is late and it does **not** rain.

The probability that the bus was late and it is raining is $0.4 \times 0.2$

So the answer is  $0.4\times0.2/(0.4\times0.2+0.6\times0.1) = 0.571$